# EF6 Database-First Navigation Properties without a defined Foreign Key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I'm going through the process of implementing entity framework into our project to move us away from ADO.net. For the most part, everything is rather simple, but I have some cases where there is no foreign key relationship in the database, yet the fields are often treated like foreign keys.

For example, we have a dimensional database that contains many different tables that are in fact referencing other tables in the database, but due to performance and the nature of dimensional databases, there are no explicitly defined relationships. To use this database with entity framework, the joins required to navigate through the database would be astronomically atrocious.

Is there any good way of creating navigational properties on these models?

**EDIT**

Example create statements for the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DimMember](
    [DimMemberId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DimPatient] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DimMemberId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DimEncounter](
    [DimEncounterID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DimMemberID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DimEncounter] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DimEncounterID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Add some "slimmed down" SQL CREATE TABLE samples...and I will look at it

Comment: @PrisonerZERO I've added the bare minimum version of two of the tables to give you an example.

Comment: You could create a `View` or `Stored Procedure` and call that via from EF, then EF would map those to your model.

Comment: In EF6, you can only configure foreign key associations to properties that EF knows as primary key. In EF-core you can also refer to alternate keys.

Comment: So...you DO...or DO NOT want DimMemberId to be treated as an FK?

Comment: It needs to be treated as a FK by entity framework, but not actually have an explicit foreign key constraint within the database.

Comment: Well, if I am understanding what you want...all you 'really' need to do is 'Code First from Database' and omit (by hand) any undesired foreign key SQL generated from your migration.  EF will 'think' a foreign key exists...even though it doesn't.

Comment: Given what you are wanting & how the question is currently worded...there is no 'code solution' to display, really.  Do you also want me to create all the EF classes + migration too...I can.  Or are you good.

Comment: Unfortunately everything has to be database first, so I believe I'll just have to write some overload methods that will autopopulate the values.